# Отчет о тестировании allure+maven+junit

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, allure

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как должен выглядеть pom.xml для составления отчетов о результатах тестировании с использованием  **allure + maven + junit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем как-то так:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>io.qameta</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensource-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>allure-junit-example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example</url>
    <connection>scm:git@github.com:allure-examples/allure-junit-example.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:allure-examples/allure-junit-example.git</developerConnection>
</scm>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    <compiler.version>1.7</compiler.version>
</properties>

<name>Allure JUnit Example</name>
<description>Allure JUnit and WebDriver Usage Example</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-BETA13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.link.issue.pattern</name>
                        <value>https://example.org/issue/{}</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Для параллельного запуска  configuration нужно добавить   
<threadCount>5</threadCount>   и   
<parallel>methods</parallel>